# Envelope following using FFT bin power -> Low pass effect on the modulation transfer function

Tags: fft, modulation

I am deriving the temporal envelope of a signal (in a particular frequency band) by summing some FFT bin powers and taking the average, I do the FFT frame by frame, windowing and some overlap.

Please help me understand the following: when the envelope of the signal changes slowly (say 5 Hz), I can track the envelope fine. However when the envelope is modulated at a higher frequency, say at 100 Hz, the dynamic range and amplitude of the detected envelope are very reduced.

So the Modulation Transfer Function (MTF) of this method has a low-pass look.

I am trying to understand the reasons for this low-pass roll-off effect and the maths behind it. I see what's happening but I can't clearly conceptualise the underlying cause . It should also be possible to come up with a number regarding the slope of the MTF.

Thanks in advance!

GP,

Edit 1 : Thanks for your answer. I can't post images cause I'm a new user apparently.. so here is a link: [Link](http://s1052.photobucket.com/albums/s445/nanonash/?action=view&current=fftmoddifferences.png) . you see on the left the input signal is 4 kHz modulated by 5 Hz and I take some fft bin powers to track the 5 Hz envelope and it works fine. But at 75 Hz modulation (right), the amplitude and dynamic range of the envelope are reduced, and it gets worse as you increase the modulation freq (low pass effect). This is what I am trying to get my head around: where is this effect coming from ? Is it because I destroy phase information when I take the power of the bins ? I apply a hann window on the time domain input frames, before computing the FFT.

Comment: Can you provide some pictures? When are you performing the windowing? The window is typically a low-pass filter.

Comment: What are you _actually_ doing? Post some code and a minimal example. (i.e. code that synthesizes a signal, and then the code that processes it).

Answer (score 1):

Any set of FFT framings of the data is a form of averaging filter or FIR filter, and thus will have a low-pass filtering effect over some envelope frequency range.  You can understand this effect by treating the FFT window as a FIR filter kernel and calculating its frequency response.

If the width of your FFT window is somewhere near the period of 5 Hz, then you will be in an area of filter roll-off.  You could try a shorter window, compensate for the window roll-off, perhaps using a "flat-top" window if your frequency of interest is well within the window's passband, or use another form of enveloper follower which does not have an intrinsic roll-off in the area of interest.

Comment: thank you. I can't see a FIR kernel here though as you need at least some history (e.g one previous sample) to make a low-pass filter. Here it looks to me like a memory-less system as the time frames are independent .

Comment: If you have more than 1 sample in a window, you have history for a FIR kernel the length of that FFT window.  The filter kernel is all 1's for the default rectangular window.

Comment: This is a poor way to think about it. A multiplicative window in the time domain does _not_ in general act like a low-pass filter. There is nothing to suggest the OP is convolving the window in the time domain. Applying a multiplicative non-rectangular window is a perfectly sensible thing to do to alleviate edge effects.

Comment: The OP is convolving his window against, not a single FFT frame, but a sequence of frames.  The sequence will thus be filtered, even though invisible in any single frame.

Comment: @hotpaw2 why do you think the OP is convolving anything? It would be a distinctly strange thing to do in this situation, and isn't apparent from the question (except for the implicit frequency domain convolution from a TD window, which isn't going to be anything like a low pass filter).

Comment: It is strange, but repeatedly turning each frame into a single result sample is a form of sparse convolution.  Perhaps the FFT is distracting you?

Comment: Sparse due to decimating the convolution result by the offset of each sequential FFT window.

Comment: I agree - the Window does not do a traditional low-pass filtering by itself, I use it just to round off the edges. But I found a new way of looking at this: multiplication in the time domain is convolution in the frequency domain. And so the window (rectangular or others) puts a low-pass on the spectrum frames which can be seen as a time signal as hotpaw2 said. It should even be possible to design windows that do hi-pass , band-pass mmmm..

Comment: @hotpaw2 ah, I see now: The OP is averaging through time (I initially thought from the description he was averaging only across frequency bins). It's still not clear to me what is being summed and what is being averaged, though if there is any summation across time, then I agree there will be a filtering affect.

Comment: @GPorters The window is a red herring. The low pass filtering is performed when you average or sum _between_ FFT frames.